# SAS Concatenate variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to concatenate a string "AT" with the microseconds retrieved from the current timestamp, but it s not working as expected. Can i get some help please?

```
proc sql;

select * into :timestampcur
from connection to db2
(select char(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
 from sysibm.sysdummy1
);
quit;

%put current_timestamp=&timestampcur.;

%let X =
     %sysfunc(compress ( %sysfunc(substr(&current_timestamp.,21,6))));

%let Y = "AT" || &X.;

%put Y=&Y.;

Output: 

Y = "AT" || 335491
```

Comment: You want the time from DB2 database instead of the time from the computer where SAS is running?  Why did you put the quotes and the spaces and the pipe characters into Y if that is not what you wanted?  Please show what you wanted Y to contain.  Is there some reason you want the string in a macro variable instead of an actual variable?

Comment: You should understand SAS macro is rather a pre-compiler langsuage than a programming language. Macro variables are just snippets of text, typically used to store fragments of code. By default, they are only evalued AFTER being inserted into the code, just before the code is compiled. _(Next you should understand SAS is not compiled as, like for instance COBOL or C++, niether interpreted during execution, as for instance javaScript or VBA, but stepwise compiled. A step is usually a SQL query, proc or a datastep.)_

Comment: Why do you want the milliseconds? What are you going to use them for?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about just storing the string into a macro variable then just remove the unneeded characters from your code.

```
%let Y=AT&X.;
```

Note that your code seems to be assuming that the DB2 expression

```
char(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
```

will return a string that is at least 26 bytes long without any leading spaces and that the bytes 21-26 are the digits that represent milliseconds.

Comment: microseconds from SAS has value rounded like "2022-05-04-11.44.15.700000,2022-05-04-11.44.18.400000,2022-05-04-11.44.21.900000" whereas DB2 timestamp has the actual microseconds. but the problem i have now is to convert Db2 timestamp into numeric value

Comment: The DATETIME() function (at least on Windows) only returns milliseconds.  But since SAS stores all numbers are floating point you could store more digits.  Are you saying if select CURRENT TIMESTAMP from DB2 and transfer it into a SAS datetime value the micro seconds are not preserved?   Note that the datetime value for now is already a 10 digit integer.  If you try to append another 6 significant digits you will exceed the number of decimal digits that can be exactly represented in IEEE floating point numbers.

Comment: no the timestamp from SAS and DB2 are different.  so i tot of converting Db2 timestamp into numeric using SAS. any idea how I can do it?  i have tried %let currtms = input(&timestampcur,anydtdtm26.); but it didnt return the numeric value

Comment: Just copy it directly as an actual number.  `create table db2ts as select * from connection to db2 (select current timestamp as ts from sysibm.sysdummy1);`

Answer (score 1):

Why not create two macrovariables in the first place?

```
proc sql;
select timestampcur, compress(substr(timestampcur,21,6))
into :timestampcur, :Y
from connection to db2
(select char(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) as timestampcur
 from sysibm.sysdummy1
);
quit;
```

Comment: any idea how can i convert the db2 timestamp into SAS numeric value, i ll be using the timestamp to insert into another table? I have tried the below 
%let currtms = input(&timestampcur,anydtdtm26.);

Answer (score 1):

A TIMESTAMP value in DB2 will be returned as a SAS datetime value, which is decimal seconds from epoch 01jan1960:00:00:00.

```
proc sql;
  select (ts-int(ts)) * 1e6 into :db2_timestamp_msportion
  from connection to db2
  ( select CURRENT TIMESTAMP as ts from sysibm.sysdummy1 )
;
quit;
```